# How can I retrieve the result of a trained model with Kubeflow Fairing?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, kubernetes, tensorflow-serving, kubeflow

I am using [Kubeflow fairing](https://github.com/kubeflow/fairing) to train a [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) model on Kubernetes. The training succeeds but now I want to [serve a prediction endpoint](https://github.com/kubeflow/fairing/blob/master/fairing/deployers/serving/serving.py#L15).

How can I retrieve the saved TensorFlow session (weights, biases etc.) from the training step so that I can do this? At the moment the result of the training step is saved inside the Docker container running on the Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Hi, I'm not familiar how to use "Kubeflow Fairing to train a model" but as per research and documentation:
Please follow this tutorial with examples how to save model to [local PVC or with google cloud storage gcs](https://github.com/kubeflow/examples/tree/master/mnist). There is another [example](https://github.com/kubeflow/fairing/blob/master/examples/prediction/xgboost-high-level-apis.ipynb)
Please share with you findings

Answer (score 0):

I had misunderstood the scope of Kubeflow fairing - at the time of writing it doesn't support copying the trained model from the fairing job to where the code was run from, nor is this necessarily desirable.

I instead used the [Minio](https://min.io/) instance provisioned by Kubeflow to store and retrieve tarballs of trained models.